# Have php form submit email and a text file

Tags: php, file, email, text

Hi I have  a form that lately has been having some issues. The email is not always going through, have checked spam folder, that's not it.

I wanted to know how to append the process to also write to a text.
 Here is my form

```
   if(md5($verif_box).'a4xn' == $_COOKIE['tntcon']){
    // if verification code was correct send the message and show this page

    $message = "Lastfour: ".$lastfour."\n".$message;
    $message = "Exchange: ".$exchange."\n".$message;
    $message = "Phone: ".$phone."\n".$message;
    $message = "bedrooms: ".$bedrooms."\n".$message;
    $message = "resortname: ".$resortname."\n".$message;
    $message = "From: ".$from."\n".$message;
    $message = "lastName: ".$lastname."\n".$message;
    $message = "Name: ".$name."\n".$message;
    mail("myeamail@mail.com", 'Online Form: '.$resortname, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n\n".$message, "From: $from");
    // delete the cookie so it cannot sent again by refreshing this page
    setcookie('tntcon','');
} else {
    // if verification code was incorrect then return to contact page and show error
    header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?subject=$resortname&from=$from&message=$message&wrong_code=true");
    exit;
}
?>
```

is there a edit to this or do I need to run another process?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the `SwiftMailer` PHP mail library? Usually a lot better than the `mail` function.

Comment: Hi thanks  I'll may have to try that I have about 100 specific forms, with 3 custom mailers.. I need to create something more dynamic to sort the specific types of inquires

Answer (score 0):

To write to a text file just add this section where you want the process to be carried out

```
$myFile = "myFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "text I want to write in the file\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but it wouldn't write to the file  It's hard to reply here but I guess I need the order and correct code to insert $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "$name | $lastname | $from | $resortname | $bedrooms | $phone | $exchange | $lastfour\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);      is that the correct format?